# react-sortable-hoc reactJS library sorting issue

Tags: reactjs, sorting, npm

I'm trying out a sample using react-sortable-hoc. Sortables are failed to keep the state on sorting. Have a look at the GIF.

[image]

Below is my sample code..

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {SortableContainer, SortableElement, arrayMove} from 'react-sortable-
hoc';
// Css
import './object_library.css'

const SortableItem = SortableElement(({value}) =>
<div className="Showcase_test_horizontalItem" >
    <div>{value}</div>
    <br />
    <TestSortable />
</div>
);

const SortableList = SortableContainer(({items}) => {
return (
    <div>
        {items.map((value, index) => (
            <SortableItem key={`item-${index}`} index={index} value={value} 
/>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
});

class TestSortable extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        sum: 0
    }
    this.onAddChild = this.onAddChild.bind(this)
}
onAddChild () {
    let prevSum = this.state.sum + 1;
    this.setState({
        sum: prevSum
    });
}
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div> {this.state.sum} </div>
            <button className="my_plus_buttons" onClick={this.onAddChild}>+
            </button>
        </div>
    );
   }
 }

 class SortableComponent extends Component {
 state = {
    items: ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', 'Item 5', 'Item 6'],
 };
 onSortEnd = ({oldIndex, newIndex}) => {
    this.setState({
        items: arrayMove(this.state.items, oldIndex, newIndex),
    });
};
render() {
    return <SortableList items={this.state.items} onSortEnd={this.onSortEnd} 
    axis="x"/>;
  }
 }

 export default SortableComponent;
```

Not sure why this library is not maintaining states ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your SortableList,  you're setting a key based on the current index, which is a normal thing to do but it seems to be what causes the problem.  Make the key match the value instead and it seems to work as expected.

I'd guess the key needs to move with the underlying component.

```
const SortableList = SortableContainer(({ items }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {items.map((value, index) => (
        <SortableItem key={`item-${value}`} index={index} value={value} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
});
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! I was missing the key inside SortableItem